# Eigen multiplication assertion failed

Tags: c++, c++17, eigen

I have 2 `MatrixXd` that I want to multiply.  But I get a runtime error.

```
Assertion failed: lhs.cols() == rhs.rows() && "invalid matrix product" && "if you wanted a coeff-wise or a dot product use the respective explicit functions",
 file C:\Users\<myPathToProject>\packages\Eigen.3.3.3\build\native\include\Eigen\src\Core\Product.h, line 97
```

I've checked the size of both matrices and I should be able to multiply them together, or maybe my maths skills are wrong. Here are the content of my two `MatrixXd`:

Matrix A:

```
        1         1         1         1         1         1
0.0196078         0         1         1  0.184314  0.329412
```

Matrix B:

```
 1
 1
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

Here is the code to reproduce. `W` and `YTrain` are `double*`:

```
    double* W = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * 2);
    double* YTrain = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * 6);
    double* XTrain = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * 6);

    W[0] = -0.527407;
    W[1] = -0.0828247;

    XTrain[0] = 0.0196078;
    XTrain[1] = 0;
    XTrain[2] = 1;
    XTrain[3] = 1;
    XTrain[4] = 0.184314;
    XTrain[5] = 0.329412;

    YTrain[0] = 1;
    YTrain[1] = 1;
    YTrain[2] = -1;
    YTrain[3] = -1;
    YTrain[4] = -1;
    YTrain[5] = -1;

Eigen::MatrixXd mat_Y(6, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    mat_Y(i) = YTrain[i];

Eigen::MatrixXd mat_XTrain(2, 6);
int pos = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 1; y++)
    {
        if (y == 0)
            mat_XTrain(y, x) = 1;
        else
         {
            mat_XTrain(y, x) = XTrain[pos];
            pos++;
        }
    }
}

Eigen::MatrixXd mult = mat_XTrain.transpose() * mat_XTrain;
auto pseudo_inv = mult.completeOrthogonalDecomposition().pseudoInverse();
Eigen::MatrixXd mult_trans = pseudo_inv * mat_XTrain.transpose();
auto final_res = mult_trans * mat_Y;
```

Comment: @JeJo Code has been updated to reproduce the error.

Comment: Yes sure, I've released my mistake, sorry.

Comment: By my math, `mult_trans` should be a 6x2 matrix. mat_Y is a 6x1. Multiplying a 6x2 matrix by a 6x1 matrix should produce the error you've received.

Comment: I've updated the code to reproduce. @MatthewM. So you are telleming that `mat_Y` is a 6x1 matrix? I thought it was a 1x6 matrix... So I should redefine `Eigen::MatrixXd mat_Y(1, 6);` and insert at proper index after?

Comment: And for future reference, with Eigen, I would recommend that you be very careful with the use of `auto`. In this case, `auto pseudo_inv = ...` doesn't actually calculate the pseudo-inverse. That calculation actually occurs on the next line when you force the result to be calculated (because you store it in a MatrixXd). The Order-of-Operations you get when you use `auto` with Eigen will often not be what you expect.

Comment: Ok thank you for the tips. I'll add it's proper type.

Comment: In this particular case `auto` might not be causing you any problems. I'm just warning you about `auto` and Eigen in general. They often do not play well together.

Comment: @BeGreen Your code is telling me that `mat_Y` is a 6x1 matrix. `MatrixXd mat_Y(6, 1)` is a 6x1 matrix. Making `mat_Y` a 1x6 matrix still wouldn't resolve your issue because `mult_trans` is a 6x2 matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192391/discussion-between-matthew-m-and-begreen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the maths was impossible to multiply a 6x2 matrix with a 1x6.

With help of Matthew M. I've released my algorithm was bad. I've added a row to `XTrain`, but I didn't need it.

To recap, `XTrain` was wrong dimension.